# При инфляции фрагмента и динамическом его заполнении лаяутами, первый лаяут не добавляется

Tags: java, android-layout-inflater

Есть у меня `ViewPager`, в который через `inflater.inflate()` я добавляю свой лаяут.

```
<ScrollView android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context="ua.lantsov.vova.kepitapp.MainActivity$PlaceholderFragment"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/home_relative_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
</ScrollView>
```

Этот лаяут я динамически заполняю другими лаяутами, созданными из кода.

```
public static class PlaceholderFragment extends Fragment {
    private static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public PlaceholderFragment() {
    }

    public static PlaceholderFragment newInstance(int sectionNumber) {
        PlaceholderFragment fragment = new PlaceholderFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, sectionNumber);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main, container, false);
        int arg = getArguments().getInt(ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, -1);
        RelativeLayout main = (RelativeLayout) rootView.findViewById(R.id.home_relative_main);
        switch (arg) {
            case 1:
            {
                int countElements = getCountElements();
                ArrayList<RelativeLayout> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int q = 0; q < countElements; q++) {
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
                    relativeLayout.setId(q);
                    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GRAY);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
                    layoutParams.topMargin = 20;
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
                    if (q > 0) {
                        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, arrayList.get(q - 1).getId());
                    }
                    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    String str = Integer.toString(q + 1);
                    textView.setText(str);
                    relativeLayout.addView(textView);

                    arrayList.add(relativeLayout);
                    main.addView(relativeLayout);
                }
                int index = arrayList.size() - 1;
                View view = new View(getContext());
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 20);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, arrayList.get(index).getId());
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
                main.addView(view);
                break;
            }
            case 2:
            {
                int countElements = getCountElements();
                ArrayList<RelativeLayout> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int q = 0; q < countElements; q++) {
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
                    relativeLayout.setId(q + countElements);
                    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.GREEN);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
                    layoutParams.topMargin = 20;
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
                    if (q > 0) {
                        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, arrayList.get(q - 1).getId());
                    }
                    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    String str = Integer.toString(q + 1);
                    textView.setText(str);
                    relativeLayout.addView(textView);

                    arrayList.add(relativeLayout);
                    main.addView(relativeLayout);
                }
                int index = arrayList.size() - 1;
                View view = new View(getContext());
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 20);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, arrayList.get(index).getId());
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
                main.addView(view);
                break;
            }
            case 3:
            {
                int countElements = getCountElements();
                ArrayList<RelativeLayout> arrayList = new ArrayList<>();
                for (int q = 0; q < countElements; q++) {
                    RelativeLayout relativeLayout = new RelativeLayout(getContext());
                    relativeLayout.setId(q + (countElements * 2));
                    relativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100);
                    layoutParams.topMargin = 20;
                    layoutParams.leftMargin = 20;
                    layoutParams.rightMargin = 20;
                    if (q > 0) {
                        layoutParams.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, arrayList.get(q - 1).getId());
                    }
                    relativeLayout.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

                    TextView textView = new TextView(getContext());
                    textView.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                    String str = Integer.toString(q + 1);
                    textView.setText(str);
                    relativeLayout.addView(textView);

                    arrayList.add(relativeLayout);
                    main.addView(relativeLayout);
                }
                int index = arrayList.size() - 1;
                View view = new View(getContext());
                RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 20);
                params.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW, arrayList.get(index).getId());
                view.setLayoutParams(params);
                main.addView(view);
                break;
            }
        }
        return rootView;
    }
}
```

Метод `getCountElements`:

```
public static int getCountElements() {
    return 3;
}
```

Проблема вот в чем: первое фото — это первая страница, остальные две страницы — как на втором фото.

[image: Первая секция] [image: Вторая и третья секции]

Comment: Андроиды облы, озорны, стозевны и лаяут.

Comment: Что это означает?